# How to specify a custom set of hyphenation rules to apply only to a custom font?

Tags: fonts, hyphenation

I am creating a grammar of a fictional language, and have had a custom font created for this language.  The font has a system where characters and ligatures overlay the previous character to create more complicated "characters" with a smaller set of glyphs.  If LaTeX hyphenates a word before a character that was supposed to overlay the previous one, it looks very bad.  I have been "solving" this by manually putting \mbox around specific words that get broken as I notice them, but obviously this isn't a permanent fix.  How can I specify a custom set of hyphenation rules that only applies to text written in this custom font?  Even as simple a rule as "don't hyphenate any words and only break lines on spaces" would work, however, I want to regular English text to be hyphenated as normal.  If it matters, the font also has a lot of ligatures in it, but I haven't noticed LaTeX trying to hyphenate a word between two characters that need to form a ligature yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When switching font also switch to a new language either an existing nohyphen language or a language for which you have defined custom patterns. Unless you are using luatex loading patterns requires building a custom format as you can not load patterns into a normal tex run.

It is probably easiest to use no patterns, which would default to no hyphenation, and then use `\hyphenation` for words where you want to allow hyphens.

```
\documentclass{article}

\showhyphens{football}% hyphenates in english
\newlanguage\something
\language\something
\showhyphens{football}% but not here
\hyphenation{foo-tball}
\showhyphens{football}% but does now
\language0
\showhyphens{football}% back to english

\begin{document}

{\language\something\ttfamily % your font
  stuff here
  }

\end{document}
```

shows a log

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--3
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 foot-ball

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 6--6
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 football

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--8
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 foo-tball

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--10
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 foot-ball
```

showing that in the new language all hyphenation is disabled except words where you specify hyphenation points

Comment: Thanks!  Can I actually just call the new language command anything I want, or are only the names of real languages accepted?

Comment: @faiuwle anything I called it `\something` here but it's just a tex token name, you can call it `\mySpecialLanguageThing`  ot whatever makes sense for you

Comment: Thank you!  It seems to be working.